# Passing an object reference to a constructor, is this DI?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Being a fresh programmer, I am now learning about DI. All examples I have read are quiet complicated with interfaces etc. But here on SO I saw an answer (with like 150 upvotes) that DI is simply:

```
public A(B b)
this.b=b;
```

I.e. passing B to A.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are injecting your dependency in object A. The complexity comes with all the different ways to accomplish DI, but when you set up a project with DI and some DI framework like for example Ninject, you will get things really fast and you really will experience the benefits of this principle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Dependency Inversion, yes.  (Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection, etc.  It all goes back to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).)

Simply, if an object has a dependency on another object (or external resource) then it should require that an instance of that other object (or external resource) be provided rather than internally create it.  An example of this would be to require an object in the constructor.

(Shameless Self-Promotion: I happen to have an old introductory presentation entitled ["What Is Dependency Injection?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6Le6YJH5o8) which you may find helpful.)

**Edit:** The comments below bring up the point of whether or not `B` is a concrete or an abstract type in your example.  Ideally it should be an abstract type.  If it's a concrete type, you're still inverting the dependency on the inner functionality of `B` but you haven't completely removed the dependency.  There still exist changes you can make to `B` which require you to re-compile and re-distribute `A`.

If `B` is abstract then you can supply *any* concrete implementation to `A` and it won't care which one you use.  If `B` is concrete then `A` is coupled to only *that specific* implementation.

Comment: Not exactly right. [Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) is just "a defining characteristic of a framework". It simply describes that you can hook your code into the pipeline of a framework. Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) is all about talking to abstractions, and Dependency Injection is about injecting dependencies. If you inject a concrete type, you don't adhere to the DIP, but are still doing Dependency Injection. When interacting with a framework, you often interact with concrete types, in that case there is no Dependency Inversion.

Comment: @Steven: Abstract types are often preferred to concrete types for defining dependencies, this is true.  But I don't think they're necessary for inverting a dependency.  One could have a dependency on a concrete type for which there are no other polymorphic analogues, and one can still require an instance of that dependency rather than instantiate it.  Note also that this could be beside the point for the question, since there's no evidence that `B` is a concrete type in the question.  (You may be right on my use of "Inversion of Control", that's one of those terms often tossed around.)

Comment: The DIP states "High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions", and I think from that we can conclude that your are not adhering to DIP when you depend on a concrete 'lower level' type. So I would say: abstractions are not needed for DI, but are needed for DIP. But you're right, there's no way for us to know whether `B` is concrete or not.

Comment: I am a bit confused now, so are you saying that the example I posted is not Dependency Injection?

Comment: @user970696: If `B` is an abstract type, your example demonstrates both the functionality and the spirit of the dependency inversion principle.  If it's a concrete type, it demonstrates only the functionality :)  I very much agree with Steven on extending to the principle, and indeed the 5 S.O.L.I.D. principles are all inter-connected in this manner.  There could exist a scenario where you don't have an abstract type, but I think Steven and I are both implying that in such a scenario an abstract *wrapper* around the non-abstractable concrete type would be very useful.

Comment: Its a simple class. So its not DI after all?

Comment: @user970696: It's a very significant step *toward* DI.  Indeed, you've inverted the dependency which is at the core of the Dependency Inversion principle.  There's still a *subtle* dependency there, though.  `A` has a compile-time dependency on the existence of concrete type `B`, so you can't supply it with any *other* kind of `B`.  There still exist *some* changes you can make to `B` which would require you to re-compile `A`, meaning that `A` still has a dependency on `B`.  Less of a dependency, but it's still there.  You're very much on the right track, though.

Comment: Also instead, should I expect Ib in the constructor and have the B class implement Ib interface?  That would be ok, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user970696: It doesn't matter whether `B` is concrete or abstract. You are injecting it in the constructor and are therefor applying the Dependency Injection pattern. However, if `B` is concrete, you will be violating the Dependency *Inversion* principle.

Comment: @user970696: Yes, that would complete the inversion of the dependency.  (Though I personally dislike the "I" naming prefix, but that's another story entirely...)  The abstract type can be an interface, an abstract base class, even a concrete base class really (though much less common, and more often than not a design flaw) as long as that base class is as unchanging as any other abstraction.  As long as `A` is relying only on an abstraction and not a specific implementation.